# UIEdgeInsets different behavior with variable and hardcoded value

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a `UICollectionView` constrained to the edges of a `UIViewController`. I want to update the bottom inset of the `UICollectionView` whenever the keyboard is displayed, so as to not hide the items at the bottom of the `UICollectionView`. To that end, I set up an observer as follows:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboard(onScreen:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
}


@objc func keyboard(onScreen notification: Notification?) {
    let info = notification?.userInfo
    let value = info?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue
    guard let keyboardHeight = value?.cgRectValue.size.height else { return }
    print("Keyboard height: \(keyboardHeight)")             // This prints out 371.0
    
    // This does not change anything in the UI
    collectionView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardHeight
    collectionView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = keyboardHeight
    
    // This updates the UI correctly
    collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 371.0
    collectionView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 371.0
}
```

The `keyboard` function is called correctly whenever the keyboard appears, and it prints out the correct height as indicated in the comments in the code above.

The problem is that if I set the `contentInset` to be the variable obtained from the keyboard `Notification`, nothing changes with the UI. If I hardcode the exact same value (371.0), the UI *does* change the way I want it.

Things I have tried with no luck so far:

- Storing the value of `keyboardHeight` in a class variable and setting the `contentInset` to that.
- Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` and `updateConstraints()` on the `collectionView`.
- Creating a local copy of the `keyboardHeight` as `let heightCopy = CGFloat(keyboardHeight)`, and setting the insets to that.

I really can't wrap my head around why the behavior would be different when I set the insets to a variable compared to when I just hardcode them to be that same value. Is anyone familiar with this behavior that could help figure this out?

**UPDATE:** In an attempt to work around this problem, I was going to set up some logic to decide which hardcoded value to set the inset to. The problem is, if I wrap the call `collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 371.0` in an if-statement, it no longer works, even if it does execute. To clarify:

```
collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 371.0 // This updates the UI correctly
```

Whereas:

```
if (some statement that is true) { 
   print("if passed")
   collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 371.0
   print("insets set")
}
```

does not result in any changes to the UI, even though the print statements appear in the output. I feel like I'm going crazy here. Any and all ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 2:** If I add a call to scroll to the end of the `UICollectionView` after setting the inset, it now works. I still am not clear on why this is affected by whether you set the inset to a hardcoded constant, or why it matters whether you wrap the call in some kind of conditional, but this solved the problem for me, in case anyone else runs into this!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to replace

```
UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification
```

with

```
UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
```

because `keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` will give you always correct frame of the keyboard.

and another thing to note, you should subtract keyboard height with safeArea bottom:

```
   let bottomInset = keyboardHeight - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

Comment: Sadly this did not solve it :( Another thing I have discovered is that wrapping the ```collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 371.0``` in an if-statement makes it not work. The code "if [statement that is true] { ```collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 371.0``` } does not update the UI, but remove the if statement and it works. Similarly within a switch statement.